# Can I call more than one routes in CodeIgniter in jQuery.ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I do something like following in CodeIgniter-

```
$('#addSomeData').click(function({
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "singleroute",
        data: $("#theform").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#tableID').load('viewpage #tableID');
        }
    });
});
```

Normally, I put a route in `config\routes.php`. Something like below-

```
$routes['singleroute'] = 'myclass/mymethod';
```

Using above code everything work fine. But, I wanna trigger multiple routes on one button click. Actually, I would like to put some default value in five different tables. I know one simple way that is I can put multiple insert query for different tables in `mymethod`. Now, My question is- Can I call multiple url in one trigger?

Comment: No ajax post the values on your provided url to post data to multiple urls then you need multiple ajax requests

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this to send multiple asynchronous request at the same time:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax("singleroute/task1"),
    $.ajax("singleroute/task2")
).then(successCallback, failureCallback);
```

Then `successCallback` will fire once all the requests completed and `failureCallback` will fire if any one request fails. Read more about `when` on [jQuery website](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

CodeIgniter Route:

```
$routes['singleroute/(:any)'] = "myclass/mymethod/$1";
```

Class Method(mymethod):

```
public function mymethod($task)
{
    // Depending on the $task do something specific
}
```